# Jquery UI DatePicker Code Conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to roll the Jquery DatePicker into a site template that I have purchased but can't get the calendar to display.

So, I have stripped out all the page content and left only the scripts / style sheets etc and the div that fires the calendar.

This can be seen at http://www.flowerssameday.co.uk/TestTemplate_Date.asp

And as you will see there is no calendar.

However, if I remove the following 2 scripts from the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( jQuery('#MM ul') ) { ddsmoothmenu.init({ mainmenuid: "MM", orientation: "h", classname: "slideMenu", contentsource: "markup" }); }
</script>
<script src="assets/js/onLoad.js"></script>
```

Then the calendar shows just fine.

This can also be seen at http://www.flowerssameday.co.uk/TestTemplate_Date_Working.asp

Of course removing the scripts stops the template from working correctly.

I wonder if there is a solution to the problem of are the 2 scripts not compatible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the onload.js is a large script (too big to post) that's why I included the links the the pages so that they can be seen in the dev tools online. Hope this is ok, I can try to post the full code here if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.

The onload.js controls a fade in option for the page display. The body tag has a class that has the content as invisible and the script then fades the page in.

Changed the css and removed the onload.js and now the calendar appears just fine.